# Stuck java space after nested for loop

Tags: java

```
public class Prac 
{
    public static void main (String[] args)

    {
        for (int line = 7; line >= 1; line = line - 2)
        {
            for(int stars = 1; stars < line; stars++)
            {
                System.out.print("*");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

The output came out correct but has a new line below it.  How would I make it so there isn't a new line at the end?

```
*******
*****
***
*
// New line here
```

Comment: tried to put the output above but it is not appearing correctly.  It is a star pattern.  4 rows with 7 columns in the first row and decrease by 2 until only 1 left.  When I compile the code there is an extra new line at the end of the code that I can't seem to make it not be there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove the new line at the end you can add an if statement to your code like so;

```
public class Prac 
{
    public static void main (String[] args)

    {
        for (int line = 7; line >= 1; line = line - 2)
        {
            for(int stars = 1; stars < line; stars++)
            {
                System.out.print("*");
            }
            if((line-2) > 0)System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

This will make sure that only when there is another line being printed is there a new line

Answer (score 0):

The last iteration of your loop is when line=1.  At that point, no stars print out, but your `System.out.println();` prints a newline.  One way to fix this, would be to remove the `System.out.println();` and to put this after your `System.out.print("*");`

```
 if(stars == line-1)
      System.out.println();
```

Comment: Note though that if you neglect a `flush`/addition of a newline, `print`ed character may get stuck in the buffer. You may want to add `else System.out.flush()`.

Answer (score 0):

​​Your current code does not work.
To remove the new line at the end you need to add an if statement in your code. It is best to add the if at the top as shown below:

```
for (int line = 7; line >= 1; line -= 2){
    if (line < 7) System.out.println(); // Don't print first time
    for(int stars = 0; stars < line; stars++) {
        System.out.print("*");
    }
}
```